# Como puedo pasar este codigo a Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
Muy buena tarde  quisiera pasar  este codigo para mysqli 

<?php
/* Clase para ejecutar las consultas a la Base de Datos*/
class ejecutarSQL {
    public static function conectar(){
        if(!$con=  mysql_connect(SERVER,USER,PASS)){
            die("Error en el servidor, verifique sus datos");
        }
        if (!mysql_select_db(BD)) {
            die("Error al conectar con la base de datos, verifique el nombre de la base de datos");
        }
        /* Codificar la información de la base de datos a UTF8*/
        mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
        return $con;
    }
    public static function consultar($query) {
        if (!$consul = mysql_query($query, ejecutarSQL::conectar())) {
            die(mysql_error().'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
/* Clase para hacer las consultas Insertar, Eliminar y Actualizar */
class consultasSQL{
    public static function InsertSQL($tabla, $campos, $valores) {
        if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("insert into $tabla ($campos) VALUES($valores)")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al insertar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $consul;
    }
public static function DeleteSQL($tabla, $condicion) {
    if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("delete from $tabla where $condicion")) {
        die("Ha ocurrido un error al eliminar los registros en la tabla $tabla");
    }
    return $consul;
}
public static function UpdateSQL($tabla, $campos, $condicion) {
    if (!$consul = ejecutarSQL::consultar("update $tabla set $campos where $condicion")) {
        die("Ha ocurrido un error al actualizar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
    }
    return $consul;
}
```

}

Comment: gracias no lo había echo bien

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar a qué te refieres cuando dices: _pasar este codigo a Mysqli_? Es decir, ¿qué quieres lograr al pasar el código a MySQLi? Imagino que querrás escribir un código robusto, blindado contra la Inyección SQL, etc. pero no especificas nada de eso en la pregunta, por lo que podría crear interpretaciones diversas y respuestas que induzcan a malas prácticas de programación.

Comment: Tengo una pagina, ya lista  pero tiene las sentencias Mysql_*,  pero las configuraciones del servidor son actuales  estoces ya no aceptan esas sentencias, así que no funciona para eso necesito  que sean Mysqli. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el otro día tuve que realizar la misma migración en un servidor donde estas funciones estaban obsoletas y había que cambiarlo a mysqli así que lo tengo algo fresco. Prueba de cambiar la clase de ejecutarSQL, así:

```
class ejecutarSQL {
    public static function conectar(){
        if(!$con=  mysqli_connect(SERVER,USER,PASS,BD)){
            die("Error en el servidor, verifique sus datos");
        }            
        /* Codificar la información de la base de datos a UTF8*/
        mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
        return $con;
    }
    public static function consultar($query) {
        if (!$consul = mysqli_query(ejecutarSQL::conectar(),$query)) {
            die(mysqli_error(ejecutarSQL::conectar()).'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, probare

Comment: Cambiar un código así sin pasarlo a consultas preparadas no tiene ningún sentido... el código sigue siendo vulnerable a ataques de **Inyección SQL**.

Comment: @A. Cedano no entiendo tu protesta, ya que simplemente pide la migración  mysqli. El código si es vulnerable es porque lo era antes, además no sabemos si él trata la entrada de datos en otro lado ya que no vemos el programa entero.

Comment: _El código si es vulnerable es porque lo era antes_ Eso no es del todo cierto. Con la extensión `mysql_*`  no puedes hacer gran cosa en ese sentido. Migrar a mysqli  es algo más que ponerle una `i` después de la `l` a las funciones. Tu respuesta me parece simplista y puede inducir a malas prácticas de programación, por eso le he dado un voto negativo. Además, en ella no adviertes nada sobre posibles riesgos, muy serios, de inyección SQL. La crítica es para que hagas un esfuerzo y mejores la respuesta.

Comment: Vuelvo a insistir que los riesgos que mencionas se encuentran en ambas extensiones, por la pregunta entendí que posiblemente el código actual no funciona ya que las funciones mysql_* están obsoletas según la versión php y la configuración del servidor, al utilizar mysqli ya es posible que funcione realizando unos cambios mínimos en el programa que tiene. Y es lo que hice.

Comment: la verda soy muy nuevo, en esto pero solo necesitaba pasar las funciones mysql_*  para que funcionara en el servidor  ya que la configuración es bastante actual mysqli, y si ya esta funcionando, y si la entrada de datos la hago en otro lado,

Comment: @PabloCastellanosRomero  Es importante que te plantees por qué `mysql_*` fue declarado obsoleto y aproveches al máximo las ventajas que ofrece `mysqli` o `PDO` y que `mysql_*` no ofrece, entre ellas una muy importante: proteger tu código de la **Inyección SQL**. Sugiero que leas esta pregunta y sus respuestas: **[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)** No se trata sólo de que tu código funcione, sino de que sea seguro. Con tus consultas como las tienes, serías presa fácil de ataques que podrían ser muy lamentables.

Answer (score 0):

La podrias pasar asi:

```
<?php
/* Clase para ejecutar las consultas a la Base de Datos*/
class ejecutarSQL {
    public static function conectar(){
        if(!$con=  new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASS,DB)){
            die("Error en el servidor, verifique sus datos");
        }
        /* Codificar la información de la base de datos a UTF8*/
        $con->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
        return $con;
    }
    public static function consultar($query) {
        $con=ejecutarSQL::conectar();
        if (!$consul = $con->query($query)) {
            die($con->error.'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
?>
```

Pero cada vez que hagas una consulta volveria a conectar contra la bbdd, mejor si mantienes la conexion en una variable y la vas reutilizando.
Quedaria asi:

```
<?php
/* Clase para ejecutar las consultas a la Base de Datos*/
class ejecutarSQL {
    public static $LINK=false;
    public static function conectar(){
        if(false===$con=new mysqli(SERVER,USER,PASS,DB)){
            die("Error en el servidor, verifique sus datos");
        }
        self::$LINK=$con;
        /* Codificar la información de la base de datos a UTF8*/
        $con->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
        return true;
    }
    public static function consultar($query) {
        if(!self::$LINK){
            self::conectar();
        }
        if (!$consul = self::$LINK->query($query)) {
            die(self::$LINK->error.'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada');
        }
        return $consul;
    }
}
?>
```

La class consultasSQL no haria falta modificarla.